# Cannot request microsoft access token for OneDrive file upload within PHP

Tags: php, azure, onedrive

I need some help. Since 2 days, I'm reading several tutorials and trying out code snippets I've found to get an access token from Microsoft to upload a single small file from PHP to OneDrive. This is my current code:

```
$onedrive_tenant_id     = 'f8cdef31-a31e-4b4a-93e4-5f571e91255a';
$onedrive_client_id     = '2947eb86-xxxxxx....';
$onedrive_client_secret = '6994277d-xxxxxx....';

if ( ! empty( $onedrive_tenant_id ) && ! empty( $onedrive_client_id ) && ! empty( $onedrive_client_secret ) ) {
    $guzzle = new Client();
    $url    = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' . $onedrive_tenant_id . '/oauth2/token';
    $user_token = json_decode( $guzzle->post( $url, [
        'form_params' => [
            'client_id'     => $onedrive_client_id,
            'client_secret' => $onedrive_client_secret,
            'resource'      => 'https://graph.microsoft.com/',
            'grant_type'    => 'password',
            'username'      => 'muster.mann@web.de',
            'password'      => '123456789',
            'scope'         => 'https://graph.microsoft.com/Files.ReadWrite'
        ],
    ] )->getBody()->getContents() );
}
```

But its not working... Every time I execute the script, I'm getting different exceptions. I've ended up with this one:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException:
> Client error: `POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/f8cdef31-a31e-4b4a-93e4-5f571e91255a/oauth2/token`
> resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
> {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"AADSTS90002: Tenant
> 'web.de' not found. Check to make sure you have the  (truncated...)

I don't understand why it's so complicated to just upload a file to OneDrive via PHP.

This is the tutorial I was following: https://www.webshark.ee/how-to-upload-files-from-server-to-microsoft-onedrive-using-rest-api-and-php/

Comment: Based on some other results for AADSTS900002, it sounds like the issue could be that the user mentioned, 'muster.mann@web.de' doesn't have an M365 subscription assigned. Are you able to sign into that user and access OneDrive through a web browser?

Comment: @RyanGregg Yes! This is my personal account, including OneDrive!

Comment: The terminology is overloaded, so I apologize for asking another clarifying question - the password flow you are using here does not work with OneDrive Personal, or Microsoft Accounts. It only works for OneDrive for Business / Azure Active Directory based accounts. Since you have a tenent ID in the URL, I assume you know that already, but wanted to clarify for others who may come to the thread. If your tenant ID is 9188040d-6c67-4c5b-b112-36a304b66dad, then the account is a personal account / Microsoft Account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggestable procedure is to use `msgraph-sdk-php` for this procedure and there is a complete clue that you are using the same but need to have few more extensions.

1. Create a sample application with PHP web service. Must note down that we need to have open access office 365 account with one drive support. (https://github.com/AI-EVO/PHP-MS-Graph)
2. Check this readme tutorial from [MSGRAPH-SDK-PHP](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php)
3. Register designed application in step 1 with ADD through Graph API (https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php#register-your-application)
4. Create your permissions list and check with availability and accessibility of those.

For further reference use the [link](https://github.com/lovattj/php-skydrive)